# Can´t get ActionBar on my activity class

Tags: android

When I call `getActionBar` throws me: "The return type is incompatible with Activity.getActionBar()"
I know it's a dumb question but I can´t find the solution.

`public class ClaseContacto extends Activity{...`

```
...
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {

    return ( (ActionBarActivity)  getActivity() ).getSupportActionBar();
}
...
//More code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSupportActionBar()`? Are you using the `android.support.v7` library?

If so, then extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`. Then remove the `getActionBar()` method and Call `getSupportActionBar()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override getActionBar();
In Activity, you just need to call

```
getActionBar()
```

and it will return ActionBar object for you

You can check this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend ActionBarActivity from support-v7-appcompat library.

And then you should use getSupportActionBar()

e.g.

```
public class SampleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

}
```

and inside onCreate() function use below code to get action bar :-

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Make sure you have imported android-support-v7-appcompat library in your IDE and added that as library project in your application project from build path -> android.